# Child theme files now showing in theme editor

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, parent-child, child-process

So I decided its time I edited some HTML in my theme editor and when I clicked on it and selected the child theme there was just the style.css and functions.php folders. No template folders in sight. So I went into my docs and copied over the files from the parent theme but for some reason they still won't show in the theme editor.

I deleted the wordpress cache and browser cache and restarted my browser but the files still won't show. Both the parent and child theme are activated and everything is up-to-date so am I missing a step from the file upload process? or doing it wrong or is there a legit fault somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! I didn't properly copy the files over in my file manager in cpanel. Everyone can remain calm and go about thier lives as normal.